# What is the meaning of "auto" label next to a file name after running maven dependency : list?

Tags: java, maven

Here is the example of the response I get when I run the command: `mvn dependency:list`

```
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:     
                                                                  
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.1.6:compile -- module spring.boot.starter.web [auto]

[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.1.6:compile -- module spring.boot.starter [auto]  
      
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.1.6:compile -- module spring.boot [auto]                        

[INFO]    ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.11:compile -- module ch.qos.logback.classic
```

Here is part of my pom file:

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.6</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <camunda.version>7.20.0</camunda.version>
        <immutables.version>2.7.3</immutables.version>
        <db2.db2jcc4.driver.version>4.0.0</db2.db2jcc4.driver.version>
        <db2.db2jcc4.license.version>1.0.6</db2.db2jcc4.license.version>
        <snakeyaml.version>2.1</snakeyaml.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2022.0.4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Dependency "spring-boot-starter-web" is explicitly provided by me in the pom file. Nevertheless, the maven labelled it as auto. The question is what that "auto" here denotes.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the [`maven-dependency-plugin:list`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html) will show you information about being a [Java Module](https://dev.java/learn/modules/intro/) or not (`[auto]`, `(auto)` and nothing.).

Let us check some particular examples to understand the output and what it exactly means:

```
ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.11:compile -- module ch.qos.logback.core
```

This output means the groupId:artifactId:type:version:scope describes a package or more accurate a module which has the [module name](https://dev.java/learn/modules/intro/): `ch.qos.logback.core`. That means in other words this is a real [Java Module](https://dev.java/learn/modules/intro/) (containing a `module-info.class` in the root of the the jar file).

```
org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.14:compile -- module spring.core [auto]
```

This means that the artifact `spring-core` (with version etc.) has defined an `Automatic-Module-Name: spring.core` (within the `MANIFEST.MF` file) but based on the output it means it does not **not** contain a `module-info.class` file inside the jar file.

```
org.atteo:evo-inflector:jar:1.3:compile -- module evo.inflector (auto)
```

This means that the artifact `evo-inflector` has **not** defined an `Automatic-Module-Name: ..` in the `MANIFEST.MF` file nor does it contain a `module-info.class` within the jar file. This module name is [automatically generated.](https://dev.java/learn/modules/automatic-module/) from the artifact name which could result in illegal module names (see the rules https://dev.java/learn/modules/automatic-module/).

If you like to know the dependency tree use the `tree` goal instead of the [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html).